# Cordova plugin (navigator.camera.getPicture) to pick video is not full screen on iPad

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, video

I have an issue on iPad when using `navigator.camera.getPicture(...)`. I am trying to pick Video from library. I found that on iPad my viewer to pick video files is very small like on this screenshot [pick video on iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSWSH.png).
How can I make this view to be full screen?

This is my code to execute picking video from gallery:

```
function () {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  navigator.camera.getPicture(
    function (mediaFiles) {
      defer.resolve(mediaFiles);
    },
    function (errorData) {
      defer.reject(errorData);
    },
    {
      quality: 100,
      allowEdit: false,
      mediaType: Camera.MediaType.VIDEO,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: You can't, this is how it works

Comment: I added improvement tasks here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10373?jql=text%20~%20%22pick%20video%22